# Connect to a SQL Server analysis service cube from Ubuntu

Tags: sql, ubuntu, ssas, libreoffice

Does anyone know If it is possible to conect from libreoffice to a SQL Server analysis service cube?

Comment: As far as I know it's just a tcp/ip connection on a port. The challenge is finding a client/driver that runs on ubuntu that can understand it.

Comment: You could try this: http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/olap-calc-extension

Comment: I tried those extension but with none results. So far I installed Windows 8 and Microsoft Office on VBox ....